# Different human reference genomes from NCBI and ENSEMBL, and variant annotation with Variant Effect Predictor (VEP)

Tags: variant-calling, reference-genome, ensembl, ncbi, vep

**Background**: I have been working on a human variant calling pipeline, from whole exome reads to variant annotation.
For variant annotation I used the [Variant Effect predictor (VEP)](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_cache.html#:%7E:text=For%20most%20of%20the%20functionality,database%20(e.g.%20homo_sapiens_core_109_38)%20installed.), which is [Ensembl](https://www.ensembl.org/index.html) based.

I have used the [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) reference genome GRCh38.p14 and the older version GRCh37.p13. The latter version was for comparison with older variant calling pipelines. It is about the latter geneome version I want to continue the discussion.

**Problem**: I sparked a little discussion due to the use of different versions of "hg19" genome (GRCH19, B37, NCBI, Ensembl) in a research project. This is related to [this article](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360035890711-GRCh37-hg19-b37-humanG1Kv37-Human-Reference-Discrepancies). Due to discrepancies in these versions, I also wholeheartedly believe these cannot be used interchangeably. But this also got me thinking about using VEP, based on Ensembl and likely their reference genome, while I also used in my pipeline the reference genome of NCBI. When I look at just two example genes, you can already notice the difference:

[image]

**Question 1**: is VEP able to correctly annotate variants likely based on the Ensembl reference genome, while I am using the NCBI reference genome?

**Question 2**: any thought/knowledge on using the one or the other reference genome, Ensembl or NCBI?

**Question 3**: Follow-up on Question 2, how do these versions relate to the UCSC version? There does not seem to be a cache for this version?

Comment: VEP asks you to pick a specific cache when you annotate, so you choose if you want NCBI or EnsEMBL. I prefer the latter because it is comprehensive

Comment: Hi, please don't answer the question in the question body, write it as a seperate answer to the question.